# React Native ListView crashes when ListView.DataSource is updated

Tags: react-native

Updating a ListView.DataSource on Android causes a NullPointerException if list is long enough that it does not all fit on screen.

Here's a sample project with code that illustrates the bug: https://github.com/npomfret/react-native-bug-reports/tree/master/ListViewUpdatingBug

It does not appear to happen on IOS.

I'm using react native 0.19.

[image]